# Best way to model and display complex schedule in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a schedule for my workgroup that involves around 70 people covering around 50 different types of shifts. In total, it's approximately 300 assignments per week. Which shifts are needing coverage will vary on a day to day basis, but will remain constant week to week. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to model this and display it in a webapp.

Right now, I've got the following models:

```
class ShiftName(models.Model):
   # Each generic shift
   ...

class Employee(models.Model):
   ...

class ShiftAssignment(models.Model): 
   # The actual individual shift coupled with a foreignkey to the employee assigned to that shift
   ...
```

Then for displaying this, it will look something like this:

```
        M       T      W      Th      F      Sat      Sun
Shift1  Bob           Sally   Sally  Jim     Chris
Shift2  Sally   Bob           Chris  Bob     Sally    Chris
Shift3  Jim           Chris   Mark           Bob
...
Shift40 Mark    Mark          Bob                     Sally
```

Right now, I've got my HTML modeled like so:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <table>
                {% for shift in shifts %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{shift}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}                    
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    {% for date in dates %}
                    <td>{{date.date}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for date in dates %}
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                {% for shift in shifts %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{% getassignment date.id shift %}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}                                
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </table>
```

What I've tried:

1. Generating an "empty" shift assignment even on days when that shift is not needed. This way I can iterate through

```
{% for shift in ShiftName.objects.all %}
    {% if shift.employee is not None %}
        {{shift.employee.name}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, but involves making a lot of extra database objects that I'll never actually use.

2. Using a simpletag to identify the assigned employee (shown in the big block of code above).
   This also works but is very slow because the page has to make ~5000 separate queries to the database on each page load.

I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this without generating a bunch of empty objects? Anyone have any advice?

---

Updated with additional model code:

```
class ShiftName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    days = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)]
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=days, blank=True, null=True)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('firstname', 'lastname')
        ordering = ['lastname']  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname + ', ' + self.firstname


class Date(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)   
   dayofweek = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.dayofweek = self.date.weekday()       
       super(Date, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



class ShiftAssignment(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Date, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shiftassignments")
    shiftname = models.ForeignKey(ShiftName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shiftassignments")
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shiftassignments", blank=True, null=True)    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('date', 'shiftname'))
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting app!  Could you share some fields on your model class code?  My first word of advice is to dig into how you might query the data you're looking for.  Django's ORM is incredibly powerful, and you may be able to build out a structure that you can loop through with one query.  Bottom line, start with your database.  The right query might simplify your template.

Comment: Edited to add more code. I've toyed around with the ORM trying to solve this, but run into difficulty in displaying it properly in HTML. Like how I would make a queryset that would recognize "this shift on this day should be empty, so put a blank box here". My thought is to somehow pass the shiftname from a <th> or something, then check if the queryset shiftname matches that? But I'm not sure that would work and/or be efficient on the database

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you only ever have to show one week at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a much improved method. Not sure if this is the *optimal* method, but it's a HUGE improvement over what I had.

I didn't want to create a bunch of empty database objects just to fill space, but realized I could instead create a list and assign an empty item to that list instead. This way, I avoid a bunch of empty objects in my database but still get the placeholder functionality. This is what my list-generating function looks like:

```
shift_assignments = ShiftAssignment.objects.order_by('shiftname__order', 'date').values_list('shiftname__order', 'date__id', 'employee__lastname')
    shift_assignment_list = [0 for _ in range(8988)] # 8988 is the distinct shift types * the days in the schedule, which I'm doing 12 week blocks so this is 106 * 84
    for shift in shift_assignments:
        index = ((shift[0]-1) * 84 + shift[1]) - 1 # Find the location to insert the lastname into the list
        shift_assignment_list[index] = shift[2] # Insert the employee name at that index
```

So the output of my shiftassignments queryset would be something like ('17', '15', 'Smith') where 17 is the row # and 15 is the column #. So to get the exact index location, account for changes from 1 index to 0 index, looks like this (shift[0] - 1) * 84 + shift[1] - 1

Then I just loop through my shift_assignment_list, ignoring the space when output is 0, otherwise printing the employee's lastname, and make a break in my forloop every 84 items like so:

```
<table class="table" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
    {% for date in dates %}
        <td style="min-width: 200px;">{{date.date}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for employee in shift_assignment_list %}
        <td style="min-width: 200px">
            {% if employee != 0 %}
            {{employee}}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:84 %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it works well.

Took my load time from 9.4s to 0.007s, so I'd call that a success! Additionally, once I generate that list once, I could save it as a constant rather than having to regenerate it each time, potentially lowering my loadtime even further. But that's probably unnecessary given how quickly it loads right now.

Comment: You anticipated what my suggestion was going to be here: "realized I could instead create a list and assign an empty item to that list instead".  Good call.  Not sure it's a requirement you have, but I was also going to add something like, start with your date range, so that you have a 'moving table'.  I.e., when the table is rendered, it gets the next X dates, or shows a two week lookahead, or something like that.  Maybe something you've already done.  Congrats on that performance improvement.

Comment: That's a great idea, and as I move this closer to production and scaling I'll definitely implement that. Thanks for your thoughts!